# I want to count IF both condition are true Logically count by AND excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two Columns both are categorical columns. Like `Age_group` and `Engagement_category`. And I want to get count no. of each engagement_category in each Age_group.

This is like GROUP BY function in SQL.

```
| Engagement_category | Age_group |
|:-------------------:|:---------:|
| Nearly Engaged      | 21-26     |
| Not Engaged         | 31-36     |
| Disengaged          | 36-41     |
| Nearly Engaged      | 21-26     |
| Engaged             | 21-26     |
| Engaged             | 26-31     |
```

I tried Excel COUNTIFS function but it is showing the count of each unique value in the criteria range that I have provided.

Expected OUTPUT is something like this.

```
| Age_group | Engaged | Nearly Engaged | Not Engagaged | Disengaged |
|:---------:|:-------:|----------------|---------------|------------|
| 21-26     | 1       |                |               |            |
| 26-31     |         |                |               |            |
| 31-36     |         |                |               |            |
| 36-41     |         |                |               |            |
| 41-46     |         |                |               |            |
| 46-51     |         |                |               |            |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` function, see document: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B, "21-26", A:A, "Engaged")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a pivot table:

[image: Demo]

> Highlight the source data which is the 2-Column table including headers, go to `Insert` tab and click the **Pivot Table** button, set up the **Rows**, **Columns** and **Values** column as below:

[image: Set up]

The key is to drag the `Engagement_Category` to both **Columns** and **Values** field.